# how to programmatically show a colored disk behind a UIImageView, in swift on an iOS device

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, uiimageview

I have an icon that I programmatically display.
How can I display a solid, colored disk behind the icon, at the same screen position?

Icon is opaque.

I will sometimes programmatically change screen position and disk's diameter and color.

Here's how I programmatically display the icon now.............

```
DispatchQueue.main.async
{

       ViewController.wrist_band_UIImageView.frame = CGRect(   x: screen_position_x, 
                                                               y: screen_position_y,
                                                               width: App_class.screen_width,
                                                               height: App_class.screen_height)
}
```

**UPDATE #1**   for D.Mika below...
[image]

**UPDATE #2**   for D.Mika below...

```
import UIKit
            import Foundation


class ViewController: UIViewController 
{
    static var circleView: UIView!

    static let wrist_band_UIImageView: UIImageView = {
       let theImageView = UIImageView()
       theImageView.image = UIImage( systemName: "applewatch" )
       theImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false 
       return theImageView
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad()     
    {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            view.addSubview( ViewController.wrist_band_UIImageView )
        // Init disk image:
        ViewController.circleView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 100.0, height: 100.0))
        ViewController.circleView.backgroundColor = .red
        ViewController.circleView.layer.cornerRadius = view.bounds.size.height / 2.0
        ViewController.circleView.clipsToBounds = true
            // Add view to view hierarchy below image view
        ViewController.circleView.insertSubview(view, belowSubview: ViewController.wrist_band_UIImageView)


        App_class.display_single_wearable()
    }
 }

 class App_class
 {
    static var is_communication_established = false
    static var total_packets = 0

    static func display_single_wearable()
    {
                ViewController.wrist_band_UIImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0,
                                                                      width: 100, height: 100)

                ViewController.circleView.frame = CGRect(   x: 0,
                                             y: 0,
                                             width: 100,
                                             height: 100)
                ViewController.circleView.layer.cornerRadius = 100
    }

    static func process_location_xy(text_location_xyz: String)
    {}
} // App_class
```

[image]

Comment: Depends, are you using constraints or setting frames?

Comment: aheze:  Just what's in the code.  Programmaticaly only.  No layout.  No IB.

Comment: Replace `ViewController.circleView.insertSubview(view, belowSubview: ViewController.wrist_band_UIImageView)`with `view.insertSubview(ViewController.circleView, belowSubview: ViewController.wrist_band_UIImageView)`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The following answer works.

The answers from d.mika above did not work.  Plus, he was insulting.  ;-)

```
// Show red circle
    let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: 200, y: 400), radius: CGFloat(40), startAngle: CGFloat(0), endAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi * 2), clockwise: true)
    
    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.path = circlePath.cgPath
    
    // Change the fill color
    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    // You can change the stroke color
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    // You can change the line width
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 3.0
    
    view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can display a colored circle using the following view:

```
circleView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 100.0, height: 100.0))
circleView.backgroundColor = .red
circleView.layer.cornerRadius = view.bounds.size.height / 2.0
circleView.clipsToBounds = true
// Add view to view hierarchy below image view
view.insertSubview(circleView, belowSubview: wrist_band_UIImageView)
```

You can change it's position and size by applying a new frame. But you have to change the layer's cornerRadius accordingly.

This is a simple example in a playground:
[image: Playground sample]

Edit:
I've modified the sample code to add the view the view hierarchy.
BUT, you still need to adjust the circle's frame, when you modify the image view's frame. (and the cornerRadius accordingly). For example

```
DispatchQueue.main.async
{
    
    ViewController.wrist_band_UIImageView.frame = CGRect(   x: screen_position_x,
                                                            y: screen_position_y,
                                                            width: App_class.screen_width,
                                                            height: App_class.screen_height)
    circleView.frame = CGRect(   x: screen_position_x,
                                 y: screen_position_y,
                                 width: App_class.screen_width,
                                 height: App_class.screen_height)
    circleView.layer.cornerRadius = App_class.screen_width
}
```

And you need to add a variable to the viewController holding the reference to the circle view, like:

```
var circleView: UIView!
```

Comment: Setting an explicit frame only works until the first time AutoLayout is triggered and updates the layout of all the views in the view controller. It's much safer to add layout anchors to the colored view that set up it's layout constraints.

Comment: I'm not using auto-layout.

Comment: I pasted the code into end of viewDidLoad() but nothing displays.

Comment: This is just an example for how to create a UIView, that shows a colored circle. It does not makes any assumption about which kind of layout is used nor does is insert this view into the view hierarchy.

Comment: I just tried using your circleView method (see UPDATE #2) and shows icon but not red disk.

Comment: Your problem is not really that you don't know how to display a red circle. Your problem is that you don't know anything about Swift or iOS development, I'm afraid. Please don't take it personally, but you should read up on the basics first.

Comment: D.Mika: You are incorrect.  I've programmed iOS since 2010.  Am new to swift but it's easy to figure out.  Yes, I don't know how to display red circle.  That's the question I'm asking.  Your examples don't work:  I did File > new > Playground... then pasted your "simple example in a playground" but got no red disk. Please see UPDATE #1 above.

Comment: @DougNull: I'm sorry if you feel insulted. But the content of your answers or comments suggests that there are gaps in knowledge. Since English is not my native language, it could be that the wording came across wrong.